# How to loop through multiple json array and display result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looping through JSON result but i have multiple arrays in my response.

**In below line i want to display only killdata response**

```
trHTML += '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + value.killdata.AcctNo + '</td></tr>';
```

**In below line i want to display only raildata response**

```
 trRailHTML += '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + value.raildata.kill_date + '</td></tr>';
```

Please suggest how to show two array data in two different tables.

**Below is my response.**

```
{"raildata":[{"id":15,"kill_date":"2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00","rail_no":1,"scale_no":10,"created":"2019-03-26T07:35:01+00:00","modified":"2019-03-26T07:35:01+00:00","is_deleted":0}],"killdata":[{"id":59,"acct_id":1883,"KillDate":"2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00","AcctNo":"UP1011","account_drpdown":"112 | Archbold Elevator (1011) | Misc 1011 | None | UP1011 | OH","BarnHogs":22,"LiveWt":22,"InvAmt":"1","Condemned":1,"Hauling":"1","PrintEvery":null,"Adjustment":11,"BegNo":null,"EndNo":null,"GroupedAcct":"UP","GroupRecId":"138","GroupAcctDesc":"Archbold Elevator (1011); Misc 1011- None","RecCreationTime":"2019-03-25T10:41:14+00:00","MPRState":"OH","Ownership":"ROUTH","NotRouthCompany":null,"Country":"US","CalculationPurchaseType":null,"CalculationCarcassBasePrice":null,"CalculationLiveBasePrice":null,"created":"2019-03-25T10:41:14+00:00","is_deleted":0},{"id":102,"acct_id":1883,"KillDate":"2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00","AcctNo":"UP1011","account_drpdown":"3 | Black, Bryan | PGI | None | UP1011 | OH","BarnHogs":11,"LiveWt":0,"InvAmt":"","Condemned":0,"Hauling":"","PrintEvery":null,"Adjustment":null,"BegNo":null,"EndNo":null,"GroupedAcct":"UP","GroupRecId":"19","GroupAcctDesc":"Black, Bryan; PGI- None","RecCreationTime":"2019-03-26T08:09:51+00:00","MPRState":"OH","Ownership":"ROUTH","NotRouthCompany":null,"Country":null,"CalculationPurchaseType":null,"CalculationCarcassBasePrice":null,"CalculationLiveBasePrice":null,"created":"2019-03-26T08:09:51+00:00","is_deleted":0}]}
```

**Below code which is working but i want to display killdata result in one table and raildata result in second table..**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.read').prop('disabled', true);
$('#client_treat_date').datepick({ 
    onClose: function(dates) { 
        $(this).blur();
        ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'Killsheets', 'action' => 'listajaxkilldata']) ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {killldate: $("#client_treat_date").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#ibox1').children('.ibox-content').toggleClass('sk-loading');  
                var trHTML = ''; 
                var trRailHTML = ''; 
                $(response).each(function (i,value) {                                
                    trHTML += '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + value.killdata.AcctNo + '</td></tr>';
                    trRailHTML += '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + value.raildata.kill_date + '</td></tr>';
                });                              
            $('#listKill').html(trHTML);
            $('#listRail').html(trRailHTML);
        }            

    }        
}); 
});
```

Comment: Aren't #listKill and #listRail two different tables?

Comment: Yes its two different tables but i am not getting how to display my result in two different table from response.bcz i have two arrays raildata and killdata in my response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attempting to loop through the response object. You instead need two separate loops through the arrays contained in the `killdata` and `raildata` properties of that object.

Note that this can be done more succinctly by using `map()` to generate arrays which contain the HTML strings of each row to be added to the tables. Try this:

```
var trKillHTML = response.killdata.map(function(killdata) {
  return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + killdata.AcctNo + '</td></tr>';
});

var trRailHTML = response.raildata.map(function(raildata) {
  return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + raildata.kill_date + '</td></tr>';
});

$('#listKill').html(trKillHTML);
$('#listRail').html(trRailHTML);
```

```js
var response = {
  "raildata": [{
    "id": 15,
    "kill_date": "2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00",
    "rail_no": 1,
    "scale_no": 10,
    "created": "2019-03-26T07:35:01+00:00",
    "modified": "2019-03-26T07:35:01+00:00",
    "is_deleted": 0
  }],
  "killdata": [{
    "id": 59,
    "acct_id": 1883,
    "KillDate": "2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00",
    "AcctNo": "UP1011",
    "account_drpdown": "112 | Archbold Elevator (1011) | Misc 1011 | None | UP1011 | OH",
    "BarnHogs": 22,
    "LiveWt": 22,
    "InvAmt": "1",
    "Condemned": 1,
    "Hauling": "1",
    "PrintEvery": null,
    "Adjustment": 11,
    "BegNo": null,
    "EndNo": null,
    "GroupedAcct": "UP",
    "GroupRecId": "138",
    "GroupAcctDesc": "Archbold Elevator (1011); Misc 1011- None",
    "RecCreationTime": "2019-03-25T10:41:14+00:00",
    "MPRState": "OH",
    "Ownership": "ROUTH",
    "NotRouthCompany": null,
    "Country": "US",
    "CalculationPurchaseType": null,
    "CalculationCarcassBasePrice": null,
    "CalculationLiveBasePrice": null,
    "created": "2019-03-25T10:41:14+00:00",
    "is_deleted": 0
  }, {
    "id": 102,
    "acct_id": 1883,
    "KillDate": "2019-03-27T00:00:00+00:00",
    "AcctNo": "UP1011",
    "account_drpdown": "3 | Black, Bryan | PGI | None | UP1011 | OH",
    "BarnHogs": 11,
    "LiveWt": 0,
    "InvAmt": "",
    "Condemned": 0,
    "Hauling": "",
    "PrintEvery": null,
    "Adjustment": null,
    "BegNo": null,
    "EndNo": null,
    "GroupedAcct": "UP",
    "GroupRecId": "19",
    "GroupAcctDesc": "Black, Bryan; PGI- None",
    "RecCreationTime": "2019-03-26T08:09:51+00:00",
    "MPRState": "OH",
    "Ownership": "ROUTH",
    "NotRouthCompany": null,
    "Country": null,
    "CalculationPurchaseType": null,
    "CalculationCarcassBasePrice": null,
    "CalculationLiveBasePrice": null,
    "created": "2019-03-26T08:09:51+00:00",
    "is_deleted": 0
  }]
}

var trKillHTML = response.killdata.map(function(killdata) {
  return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + killdata.AcctNo + '</td></tr>';
});

var trRailHTML = response.raildata.map(function(raildata) {
  return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + raildata.kill_date + '</td></tr>';
});

$('#listKill').html(trKillHTML);
$('#listRail').html(trRailHTML);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="listKill"></table>
<table id="listRail"></table>
```